# HTML & CSS - DOM traversal

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Game Design</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="GameIdea" href="GameIdea.html">Link 1</a>
    <a id="GameMechanics" href="GameMechanics.html">Link 2</a>
    <a id="GameCharacters" href="GameCharacters.html">Link 3</a>
    <a id="Inspiration" href="Inspiration.html">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById(pathShort); //e.g. pathShort == GameIdea
var anchorParent = anchor.parentNode;
var button = anchorParent.previousSibling;
button.classList.add("active");
```

The issue is this - I don't want the anchor element:`document.getElementById(pathShort);`

I want the button element, therefore as you can see I use `anchor.parentNode;` to get the `div` that the anchor is in, and then `anchorParent.previousSibling;` to get the element beside the `div`, before not after.

In my mind I thought this would work but in console I get the error `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`, therefore the variable `button` must be effectively `null` or `empty`, meaning my method of DOM traversal prior to the 'add' call has not worked.

Comment: `var button = document.querySelector('button.dropbtn')[0];`

Comment: _"therefore the variable "button" must be effectively null or empty"_ - No. The error is clear: `.classList` is `undefined`. If `button` would be `null` the error would be `TypeError: null has no properties`

Comment: Just give the button an `id`. ... `var anchor = document.getElementById(pathShort); //e.g. pathShort == GameIdea` seems like you are explicitly looking for the anchor.

Comment: Just `console.log(button)` or check its `.nodeType`. It won't be a `<button>`

Comment: `previousSibling` returns any type of a sibling node, also the white-space nodes. You need `previousElementSibling` to refer the button.

Comment: `console.log(button)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `previousSibling` method was returning an empty text node (containing nothing but white space), which is not an element and does not have a `classList` property. `previousSibling` returns the previous node whether it is an element or not. You can change it to `previousElementSibling` to get the button element, because it returns only the previous element, ignoring other types of nodes.

```js
var pathShort = "GameIdea";
var anchor = document.getElementById(pathShort);
var anchorParent = anchor.parentNode;
var button = anchorParent.previousElementSibling;
button.classList.add("active");
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Game Design</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="GameIdea" href="GameIdea.html">Link 1</a>
    <a id="GameMechanics" href="GameMechanics.html">Link 2</a>
    <a id="GameCharacters" href="GameCharacters.html">Link 3</a>
    <a id="Inspiration" href="Inspiration.html">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not "empty". It's the white space between the anchor and the button element.

Comment: So whitespace is an element?

Comment: @GetSet No, but a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)

Comment: @Andreas Yes you are correct. I meant only that it had no visible text, but that is not technically considered empty. I will update my post to clarify.

Comment: Makes sense then. @Andreas  Makes sense that whitespace would be an element i understand now... Becomes an issue in formatting to get the code correct. Or the pre-processor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use...

`var button = document.querySelector(".dropbtn")`

This will get the first element with the class dropbtn (The button element in this case).

If you're trying to add a class within the button element. I'd recommend you;

`button.setAttribute("class", "dropbtn ANY-OTHER-CLASS")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const pathShort = 'GameIdea';
const anchor = document.getElementById(pathShort);
const anchorParent = anchor.parentElement;
const button = anchorParent.previousElementSibling;
button.classList.add("active");
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Game Design</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="GameIdea" href="GameIdea.html">Link 1</a>
    <a id="GameMechanics" href="GameMechanics.html">Link 2</a>
    <a id="GameCharacters" href="GameCharacters.html">Link 3</a>
    <a id="Inspiration" href="Inspiration.html">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

when you access HTML DOM node's properties like `parentNode` or `previousSibling` you will get also non HTML nodes like Text nodes, in your code each new line creates an empty Text node, thus you get it instead of desired element.

Comment: @Andreas OP at < 100 on reputation. Oh you meant on this answer. I take that back. I liked Andriy answer actually.

Comment: A text node has no children, hence `.parentNode` would never return a text node. It doesn't even has a `.parentNode` property.

Comment: Yeah have no idea why anyone wouldnt think this wasnt the solution.